# Is "Unless if" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar

A friend pointed out to me recently that I have a tendency to preface some of my sentences with the phrase "Unless if..."

For example:

> Unless if we take the highway, we won't make it in time.

She insists that this is grammatically incorrect. Is this, and if it is, how is this sentence wrong? Would this phrasing be still incorrect if, instead, I said:

> Unless, if we take the highway, we won't make it in time.

Comment: It's not grammatical. _Unless we take the freeway, we'll be late_ = _If we don't take the freeway, we'll be late._ Since _unless_ already means "if not", another _if_ is confusing, to put it mildly.

Comment: You didn't mention what her suggestion is to correct the sentence.

Comment: **Unless if** someone claims this is an "Appalachian English" usage (which wouldn't totally flabber my ghast), I think this question is Off Topic General Reference.

Comment: @JohnLawler Does *unless* really mean *if not*, though? (Heretically) I don't believe so. I believe conditional *if* is exactly the same *item* as interrogative *if*  -  a meaningess clause-type marker (aka a *subordinator* in CamGEL-speak). The difference in meaning between interrogaive and conditional *if*-clauses, I argue, derives solely from their grammatical relations.

Comment: @Araucaria If _unless_ doesn't mean _if not_, what does it mean? I don't care about the different versions of _if_ (which I agree means _whether_ in embedded questions), but this question's about _unless if_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, if *if* is a meaningless clause marker, then it's hard for something to mean the same thing as *if*, or its negation. It would be odd to use an *if-clause* after (in CamGEL's terminology a preposition) a subordinating conjunction, but there's nothing in terms of *meaning* to prevent us from doing so. It's a bit complicated to squeeze into a comment box, but in effect, the word *if* (like subject-auxiliary inversion) is basically used to cancel presuppositions. And as this presupposition is cancelled in *unless*-clauses as much as it is in regular conditional antecedents ...

Comment: @JohnLawler it doesn't seem to me to be totally incompatible, apart from for syntactic reasons. And therefore it is of little surprise to me that it does in fact seem t be acceptable for some speakers to use *unless if* - although this is nearly entirely restricted to cases ...

Comment: @JohnLawler ... where the antecednt follows the main clause. [Here's a list from Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unless+if%22&client=firefox-b&tbs=bkt:b&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAuoWx-PncAhUSeMAKHW3uAqkQpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=631&dpr=1) in which about every fifth entry (after the first couple of pages) is a bona fide usage of *unless if* (as opposed to a case of  *unless* being used with a main clause with its own conditional antecedent). Here's some examples:

Comment: @JohnLawler  "*Making scientific progress faster doesn't necessarily mean better - unless if you're an aging philanthropist and want an answer in your lifetime*",  "*This was not usual for him, unless if there was something to gain in return.*" ,  "*Remove underlining from everywhere in your document unless if you have some of these exceptional circumstances.*"

Comment: @JohnLawler If you let me know when you've read these, I'll delete some of them, as they're a bit longish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unless* is a kind of negative of *if*—think of it as very much like “if . . . *not.”* Adding *if* to it is thus redundant, confusingly so—it makes it seem as if the main clause is being limited by *two* conditions, not one. For instance, your last example would only really make grammatical sense in the context of a larger sentence such as this:

> Unless, if we take the highway, we won’t make it in time, we really should take those scenic back roads.

In other words, *if* it is the case that *if* we take the highway we shall arrive late, then we should take the highway; otherwise, we should take the back roads, because they are more scenic. There are *two* conditionals operating here.

Comment: If interested: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/24212/8572

Comment: I agree that ['A unless B' means 'A if not B'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/612312/484417). However, your final paragraph is treating 'A unless B' as 'A if and only if (not B)', so is a tad stronger than that quoted sentence, which asserts only, "if we take the highway and will make it in time, then we really should take those scenic back roads" (which is of course irrational). To be clear: for the case of taking the highway entailling being late, the quoted sentence—contrary to your final paragraph—technically does not suggest any particular direction.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the two "just because" is grammatically wrong and confusing, but while "unless" connects two clauses, one of the clauses can be a conditional based on "if".

> We won't make it on time, unless, if the boss is in good mood, he might move the deadline.

Here we have two clauses connected by *unless*:

> We won't make it on time, unless the boss moves the deadline.

But the second clause is conditional:

> If the boss is in good mood, he might move the deadline.

That way two unrelated conjunctions are brought together - but that's accidental, definitely not a regular syntax.

Comment: I find it interesting that you use the hypothetical _might move_ in the simple ‘if’ conditional (undoubtedly grammatical) and the regular present _moves_ in the ‘unless’ clause (also undoubtedly grammatical—a hypothetical here would be ungrammatical to me) … but then maintain/reintroduce the hypothetical _might move_ when the ‘if’ conditional is embedded in the ‘unless’ clause. This latter is ungrammatical to me: to me, it _must_ be “We won’t make it on time, unless, if the boss is in (a) good mood, he **moves** the deadline”. Am I alone in this?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Absolutely don't take me as any kind of authority on that. English is my second language and this is the kind of errors I'm quite prone to make.